# Populate a dropdown list based on the another dropdown list using AJAX JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I know that this question has been asked by many before but I could not get an exact solution that resembles to my question.

I have a dropdown list called Category and a another dropdown rather a sub one called Grade.
As I select a Category(Lets say I select TV out of radio,washing machines,dvd players etc.), then the corresponding grades to that category(Lets say TV - Sony, Hitachi, Samsung, Philips..) should populate on the grade dropdown. But both the categories and grades are being fetched from the database and the queries are working perfectly.

**AJAX:-**

```
<script>
        function getGradeDetails(category){
            if(category!==""){
                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "../controller/sales.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {category:category,action:'get_grade_details'},  
                    dataType: "json"
                });
                request.done(function(json_return){    
                    //alert(json_return['grade_desc']);
                    $( "#grade" ).append( "<option>"+json_return['grade_desc']    </option>" );
                }); 
                request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                    return false;
                });
            }
            else{
                $("#grade").append('<option></option>');
            }
        }
</script>
```

**HTML:-**

```
<td>Category
    <select name="category" id="category" onchange="getGradeDetails(this.value)">
        <option></option>
        <?php 
           require_once '../model/sales.php';
           @$result=Sales::getAllCategories();
           while($value=  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value['category_code']; ?>">
            <?php echo $value['category_desc'] ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</td>

<td>Grade
<td>
   <select id="grade">
   </select>
</td>
```

**CONTROLLER:-**

```
<?php 
    require_once '../model/sales.php';
    $action=$_REQUEST['action'];

    switch($action){
        case 'get_grade_details':
            getGradeDetails();
            break;
        default :
            break;
    }        
    function getGradeDetails(){
        $category=$_POST['category'];
        require_once '../model/sales.php';
        $obj=new Sales();
        $result=mysql_fetch_assoc($obj->getGradesForCategory($category));
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

According to this code, the dropdown value on the grade does get only the first value from the DB. Eg:-Only Sony, and it avoids others-Hitachi,Samsung etc..
And moreover as I change on another category(Eg:-Washing Machines), then the Grade dropdown has values Sony(TV Grade),LG(Washing Machines Grade).

What I want is:-

1) The values should appear as a whole not just the first/single value from the DB.

2) As i change on the category(TV to Washing Machines), then values relating to TV should not appear(Sony) and only values that are pertaining to the washing machines(LG) should appear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not looping and adding all the items on the response list to the options of the select tag

```
request.done(function(json_return){    
                //alert(json_return['grade_desc']);
                **$( "#grade" ).append( "<option>"+json_return['grade_desc']</option>"**     );
            });
```

The highlighted portion should be corrected so as all the values are being added as options, something like

```
var options = '';

for (i=0;i< json_return['grade_desc'].length;i++){
   options += "<option>"+json_return['grade_desc'][i]+"</option>";
}
$("#grade").append(options);
```

The second question needs more information. Please post a snippet of the response from ajax.

Comment: Both questions are being almost solved. But if i select TV, what I get as options in the dropdown list is not just Sony, Philips BUT I get S O N Y P H I L I P S.........Almost 11 options in the dropdown list.
How can I rectify that???

Comment: I think the json response that you are receiving is stringified one. Try pareseJSON before looping.